# How add track events before a navigation occurs with Prism Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, azure-application-insights, hockeyapp

I need help.

I need to add track events in Hockeyapp before a navigation occurs with Prism Xamarin Forms, could anyone help me in an implementation with Prims in an elegant way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement INavigatingAware on your ViewModel and it will be called before navigation occurs:
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Navigation/INavigatingAware.cs